# How do I create an installer application in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, packaging, msix

Not to be confused by questions like *"How do I create an installer for a WinForms app?"*. I want to create my own layout of the installer **in** `WinForms`. I want to create my own installer, using `WinForms`, including all of the installers' functionalities such as adding registry keys, certificate, user account choice ("Me" or "All users on this computer"). Of course, I assume that reinventing the wheel is possible, but comes with a lot of complications.

That's why items like these exist:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/tool-overview

These "templates" allow you to add all functionality of an installer, including the files you wish you pack, "with the push of a button". But they already have their own UI and I do not wish to poke deeper in them to customize the UI. I want to use `WinForms` to create the UI, options such as file destination(s), optional files, progress bar(s), rollbacks, referrals to websites, ads, etc.

I do not want to create a typical WinForms project to mimic an installer, by simply having the files packed into its Resources or an external file to read/parse from, then copy them where they have to go. I would prefer using the functionalities from MSIX for instance and design my own UI. How do I accomplish this? Can I implement the MSIX Packaging functionality into a `WinForm` project then use it to calculate the progress, certificate validation, rollbacks and other mandatory behaviors of a Windows installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would highly recommend checking out [Wix#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804584/Wixsharp-WixSharp-UI-Extensions).

It has a Winforms-style designer and you can add custom actions too as far as I know.

Or if the basics work for you, you can just make a custom dialog using XML in wix. This tutorial can help you get into the basics of it: [Add-in express](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2014/02/07/add-custom-dialogs-wix-installer/)